# Objects spawning and falling down immediately in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, service, spawn-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate a table with many objects on it. But some of objects get spawned quicker than the table, and they simply fall down on the floor. Each time different ones randomly.

I am looking for way to stop physics simulation, till all the objects are spawned. Is it possible to write it somehow into launch file? "Pause physics" is a service, not a node, so it gets compicated...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10897/objects-spawning-and-falling-down-immediately-in-gazebo/) by [robofreak](https://answers.ros.org/users/953/robofreak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-08-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you call the pause physics service first, and then spawn each of your objects with the SpawnModel service?

---

Originally posted by [Matt Klingensmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/942/matt-klingensmith/) with karma: 141 on 2011-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robofreak](https://answers.ros.org/users/953/robofreak/) on 2011-08-15**:
Well, now I do almost like that: in one launch file I spawn only world and table, then I call another launch file which spawns all remaining objects. But it's a kind of workaround. I was looking for a convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can implement a 'wait for model' function in your model spawner if you have one, or use the '-wait' option in my [spawn_model](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/jade-devel/gazebo_ros/scripts/spawn_model) utility script.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IMHO cleanest approach for starting up Gazebo in cases like this is starting it in paused mode. You'll need to press the "play" button after things started up, but you'll have a very reproducible setup using only a single launch file. To start Gazebo paused, you have to provide it with the "-u" option. An example is the combination of these two launch files, using arguments: [main launch file](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_centaur/blob/master/hector_centaur_scenarios/launch/exploration_door.launch#L5), [common gazebo start launch file](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_nist_arenas_gazebo/blob/indigo-devel/hector_nist_arena_worlds/launch/start.launch).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3